# How do I write an activerecord query that only looks at the time component of a datetime field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, datetime, activerecord, time

Is it possible to do an activerecord query that only looks at the time component of a datetime field?

e.g. `Battle.where('start_time < ? and start_time > ?','12:00','06:00')`

to find all battles that were started between 6am and 12pm regardless of the day they occurred? In this example, start_time is defined as a datetime.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only way to do this is using a SQL function, if you're on MySQL you could do it like this:

```
Battle.where( 'HOUR( start_time ) >= ? AND HOUR( start_time ) <= ?', 12, 6 )
```

But this is hugely inefficient and is always going to generate a **full table scan** and you surely don't want that.

The best solution is to add columns with the hour values alone at your battle model, index them and query directly on them like this:

```
Battle.where( 'start_time_hour >= ? start_time_hour <= ?', 12, 6 )
```

Just add an before_save callback that sets this values before saving your Battle model based on the start_time property.

**EDIT**

BTW, if you're using PostgreSQL, it's capable of creating an index on the result of a function, so, if you don't mind having to stick with PostgreSQL you could just use the SQL function. And before you ask, no, i don't know how it works, I only know the database allows you to do so and that this is not available on MySQL.

Comment: Fantastic, thankyou. In development I'm in SQLite where I have used Battle.where('time(start_time) < ? and time(start_time) > ?', '12', '6') which seems to work. I'm planning to use PostgreSQL in production so can use your code. The only problem I'm noticing is that this seems to ignore my timezone (unsurprising as we're bypassing Rails). I've started to think about this but it's giving me a headache so I'll come back to it later. It might be easiest to set up the hour column with the timezone pre-converted.