# query for created_at hour

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I query for records that were created at a certain hour?  Will I need to add an hour column in the db for each record?  Ruby will return a nice value for created_at.hour but I can't use it in a query like as below:

```
results = Record.where("created_at.hour = ?", the_hour)
```

Comment: What you have will work just fine. Is the variable `the_hour` an integer?

Comment: the_hour is an integer.  The error message:  Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'created_at.hour' in 'where clause'

Comment: The problem is Rails is trying to look for a column called `created_at.hour`. Rails doesn't understand that `.hour` is actually a method.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6811480/how-do-i-write-an-activerecord-query-that-only-looks-at-the-time-component-of-a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
results = Record.where("hour(created_at) = ?", the_hour)
```

You need to use the MySQL `hour` function to extract the hour from the timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

Just for future reference for others.

If you happen to use SQLite in which `hour` function to extract the hour from the timestamp is not available, use this solution.

```
def find_record_by_created_at_hour(certain_hour)
  Record.all.select {|record| record.created_at.hour == certain_hour }
end
```